# How to restruct data model for microservices?

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, microservices, data-modeling

How to restruct data model for microservices?

for example I have a monolith application.
Lets name it 'Users and Events CRUD service'.

Users and Events a tightly coupled in terms of physical data base model. Lets data model for them:

```
Users table:
    name PK

Events table:
    title PK
    creator_user_name FK (points to Users:name)
```

And now I want to separate my monolith application to two microservices. Lets name them

1. CRUD users service
2. CRUD events service

Here I'm thinkih about separating above data model or not separating.

1 st approach is to:
    keep going with data model as above one, so both services use one database.

2nd approach is to:
    restructure my data model to look like this(where each service has its own database):

```
DB 1: users
        Users table:
            name PK    

DB 2: events
    Event table:
        title PK
        creator_user_name (indexed)
```

Considering this case, what approach is best? What is the best practice in that case?

I guess that I can simply pick 1st approach and it will be nothing wrong with it, but
what about approach #2? Is it usable int practice? Could it cause some suprising consequences later then?
I guess that approach #2 is perfecrtly fine as well but I'm not sure, so need help to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think like this: as times goes by and you add more and more services to your system.

If all of your services access the same database than you will end up having your database as a central Contact for all of your services. It's going to be very difficult to make changes since it will be hard to know what service use which tables.

If you wanna do it right go for **Approach 2**. 
Each service has it's own database,  and a microservice should not access database other than it's own.
It is perfectly fine for a service to call another service if that is needed(orchestrated method)

Best regards 
Burim

Comment: Thanks for an answer, appreciate it. I guess that with more services we need more databases, each storing some entity set. The model case(my question) emphasize that entities (users and events) are tightly coupled. So the question arises: If all tightly coupled entities should be stored in a singly database? Or their tightly 'couplness' doesn't matter? 

In other words.
I guess that when we have multiple databases each storing a set of tightly coupled entities this is good. But what when we want to separate tightly coupled database structure? Still good?

Comment: Try to defind bounded context in your system. Create one service/bounded context. Some joins you are still going to do in code, some foreign keys are going to be broken.

Comment: It is bad idea to share database just because that the model is tightly coupled. In that case it is better to have it with in the same bounded context and same service